# conditional statements in a .map function returns nothing in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to do conditional rendering on react and although the condition it's either true or false, the elements are not being rendered.
What could be the problem? Thanks

```
    <section>
                                        <li className="top-nav__item top-nav__item--active">
                                            {state.profileData[0].likes.map((like) => {
                                                console.log(like) // outputs the user id and appState.user._id
                                                like.user === appState.user._id ? (
                                                    <Link
                                                        onClick={(e) => startLikingTweet(e, tweetPost)}
                                                        to="/"
                                                        className="top-nav__link"
                                                    >
                                                        <IcomoonReact
                                                            className="top-nav__icon"
                                                            iconSet={iconSet}
                                                            color="red"
                                                            size={20}
                                                            icon="heart"
                                                        />
                                                        <span>{tweetPost.likes.length}</span>
                                                    </Link>
                                                ) : (
                                                    <a>hey</a>
                                                );
                                            })}
                                        </li>
                                    </section>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Map method is not rendering components in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70361452/map-method-is-not-rendering-components-in-react-js)

Comment: Shouldn't you be returning something?

Comment: Remember that you need to use the return keyword with a lambda WHENEVER you use curly brackets as a wrapper.

Comment: Yes, i missed that one. However, now it's rendering two conditions instead of the one which is true. Any idea why that's happening?

Answer (score -2):

You're missing a return statement inside of your `.map`, try adding a return before `like.user === appState.user._id` like the following:

```
I'm trying to do conditional rendering on react and although the condition it's either true or false, the elements are not being rendered. What could be the problem? Thanks

    <section>
                                        <li className="top-nav__item top-nav__item--active">
                                            {state.profileData[0].likes.map((like) => {
                                                console.log(like) // outputs the user id and appState.user._id
                                                return like.user === appState.user._id ? (
                                                    <Link
                                                        onClick={(e) => startLikingTweet(e, tweetPost)}
                                                        to="/"
                                                        className="top-nav__link"
                                                    >
                                                        <IcomoonReact
                                                            className="top-nav__icon"
                                                            iconSet={iconSet}
                                                            color="red"
                                                            size={20}
                                                            icon="heart"
                                                        />
                                                        <span>{tweetPost.likes.length}</span>
                                                    </Link>
                                                ) : (
                                                    <a>hey</a>
                                                );
                                            })}
                                        </li>
                                    </section>
```