# Data is not displaying in react components

Tags: reactjs

I don't understand why my fetched data is not displaying.
Data is fetched properly when i check by `console.log()` however nothing shows up in my JSX section. Code looks alight too. Anyone have idea what is wrong here?

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export const ConcertLatest = () => {
const [concerts, setConcerts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
const loadConcerts = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get("/data/concerts");

  const rawData = response.data;

  const filteredData = rawData.filter((concert) => {
    //let date = new Date(concert.datum);
    // let newestDate = new Date("2022-09-29");
    return concert.datum >= "2022-09-30";
  });

  setConcerts(filteredData);
};
loadConcerts();
}, []);

if (!concerts.length) {
return <p>Loading...</p>;
}
console.log(concerts); // getting full populated objects 
return (
<div>
  <h1>Newest concerts </h1>
  <div>
    <div className="card">
      <img src={concerts.image} style={{ width: 100 }} />
      <div className="card-text">
        <div>
          {concerts.map((concert) => {
            (<h1>{concert.name}</h1>), (<h2>{concert.datum}</h2>);
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
);
};
```

Comment: When you map your `concerts` you have an arrow function with the blocked body (`{` and `}`). Such functions have to have `return` statement to return anything

Comment: Thank you, it helped partly. Second element of concerts was displayed but the first one (concert.name) is not. `return (<h1>{concert.name}</h1>), (<h2>{concert.datum}</h2>);`

Comment: I believe this is because you use `,` js operator. The result of it is the most right value. If you want it to be displayed as part of JSX I think you need to wrap everything into some JSX element

Comment: Your code returns an error because the "map" function needs to have a return statement, instead of a function call expression

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React.js, map is not rendering components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70361452/react-js-map-is-not-rendering-components)

Comment: Yes, thank you. Solution was to return one JSX element and wrap others element inside it. Thank for help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change syntax of map function, either use return keyword with curly braces or just use round braces without return keyword. Eg

```
    <div>
     {concerts.map((concert) => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            (<h1>{concert.name}</h1>), (<h2>{concert.datum}</h2>)
          </React.Fragment>
        )
       })}
     </div>
```

Or

```
    <div>
     {concerts.map((concert) => (
          <React.Fragment>
            (<h1>{concert.name}</h1>), (<h2>{concert.datum}</h2>)
          </React.Fragment>
     ))}
     </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I removed these round braces and " , " and now its working. Solution was to wrap properties of the fetched data inside one tag.